# How do I make use of a self-defined path in Header to redirect in PHP?

Tags: php, redirect, path, header

I am trying to redirect users to a different page using the Header function in PHP like so but it doesn't work:

```
Header("Location: " . VIEW_PATH. "/somePage.html");
```

VIEW_PATH is defined in my config.php like this: 
    define('VIEW_PATH', **DIR**."\View");

The Header function is currently in my Auth Class in my Controller Folder and I am trying to redirect users to a page in my View folder.

This works but I want to make use of VIEW_PATH:
    Header("Location: ../View/somePage.html");

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Aren't you making use of `VIEW_PATH` already?

Comment: What does `VIEW_PATH` contain when you output it? `echo VIEW_PATH;`

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\Store\View

VIEW_PATH works... I've added it into an include and it works fine:
include_once(VIEW_PATH. "/registration.html");

Comment: If you're really using backslashes there `"\View"` then it ain't gonna work. Use forward slashes for paths everywhere. They work on Windows too.

Comment: It works for the include but not for Header...

Comment: Mario:

I can change define('VIEW_PATH', __DIR__."\\View"); to define('VIEW_PATH', __DIR__."/View");

but VIEW_PATH will just be changed to C:\xampp\htdocs\Store/View as opposed to C:\xampp\htdocs\Store\View

How would I get around that? :/

Comment: Change the rest too. Or use `strtr()` if you like it fiddly. Also get rid of the the drive letter. That has no meaning in HTTP header context.

Comment: it doesn't work now for my include_once(VIEW_PATH. "/registration.html"); after I replaced all the "\" with "/" and got rid of C:\. Surely there is a more simple, less fiddly way?

Warning: include_once( xampp/htdocs/Store/Store/View/registration.html) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Store\Store\Controller\Registration.php on line 16

Comment: @user1219572 Short story: You can't use a filesystem-absolute path in a context that requires a website-root-relative path. As you should have noticed by the resulting URLs. Define a separate variable.

Comment: What would I be defining a separate variable for? We'll get there eventually !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can see, your VIEW_PATH constant contains physical path on server. But you should use url path to file in your header call.

Look at this example.

```
define('VIEW_PATH', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Store\View');
define('VIEW_URL',  'http://www.example.com/Store/View');
// or define('VIEW_URL', '/Store/View');
```

P.S.
Also you should use / in your url, not  \

Comment: Thanks,

How would I go about defining a relative URL path or some sort? 

I guess I would have to find the root directory with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] but I've read that it's best not to use that since the result varies depending on different platforms. 

So what should I use in place of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?

Comment: I think you better define VIEW_URL constant inside your configuration file and use this constant. You must know where is your document root, its value do not changed until you change web-server configuration. In most cases document_root calls  'public_html' or 'httpdocs'. 
If you need to define your constant on the fly your can try this trick( but reccomend simply define constant):
1) place file into root directory, determine it directory name: $dir = dirname(__ FILE__);
2) Do this $view_url =  str_replace($dir, '', VIEW_PATH);
3) replace \ with /: $view_url = str_replace('\\', '/', $view_url)